# Microsoft Cognitive Services Emotion API. Error: 'Image size is too small or too big.'

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services

I have noticed a rather strange error with the Emotion API from the Cognitive Services suite.

Everything works just fine as long as I send it URL's. When sending it image attachments. I receive this JSON error:
`{ error: { code: 'InvalidImageSize', message: 'Image size is too small or too big.' } }`

Sending it smaller or larger versions does not help. 
Send a URL of the same image, and suddenly it works fine again.

I stream the attachment to the API service in the exact same way I do for another Cognitive Services API, namely Computer Vision. And that works great with streamed attachments.

The code is on GitHub: https://github.com/sebsylvester/botbuilder-mcs

I know the APIs are still in preview, but this is still a weird issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Emotion and Face APIs do not support chunked transfers, as noted [here](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/project-oxford/issues/15).  The 'workaround' is to load the image bits synchronously prior to making the web request.  The code [snippet](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/project-oxford/blob/master/src/face.js#L75) from that project is thus:

```
function _postImageSync(url, image, options) {
    return new _Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request.post({
            uri: host + rootPath + url,
            headers: {
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key,
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
            },
            qs: options,
            body: fs.readFileSync(image)
        }, (error, response) => {
            response.body = JSON.parse(response.body);
            _return(error, response, resolve, reject);
        });
    });
}
```