# InvalidImageSize Image size is too small or too big - HTML5, Node.js,

Tags: node.js, html, express, html5-canvas, azure-cognitive-services

Referring to : [Microsoft Cognitive Services Emotion API. Error: 'Image size is too small or too big.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806979/microsoft-cognitive-services-emotion-api-error-image-size-is-too-small-or-too)

Calling the Microsoft cognitive service for emotion recognition I get the error: 400 Bad Request: {"error":{"code":"InvalidImageSize","message":"Image size is too small or too big."}}

It runs locally on a Node.js-Server in debug mode.

The Client sends his/her image to the server which adds the subscription-key and pipes the request to Microsoft.

Client-Code:

```
function processPicture() {
  var process = function(blob){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/home/upload";
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
          alert(http.responseText);
      }
    }
    http.send(blob);
  }
  canvas.toBlob(process, "image/png", 0.70);    
}
```

Server-Code:

```
router.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    var url = 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/emotion/v1.0/recognize';

    req.headers = [];
    req.headers['content-type'] = 'application/octet-stream';
    req.headers['ocp-apim-subscription-key'] = '88ab62d300284ddXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    req.pipe(request({
        qs: req.query,
        uri: url,
        headers: req.headers
    })
    ).on('response', function(pres) {
        res.writeHead(pres.statusCode, pres.headers);
        pres.pipe(res);
    });    
});
```

I can not see that I am using "chunked transfer encoding request" which could lead to problems. (like mentioned in this post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6fb47e0d-fc9e-44f0-af3d-66887e10a72c/face-api-error-invalidimagesize-image-size-is-too-small-or-too-big-for-each-request?forum=mlapi)

I tried different image-sizes

Here is the API-Reference: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5639d931ca73072154c1ce89/operations/563b31ea778daf121cc3a5fa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a middleware und creating a new request worked for me:

---

```
app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: "application/octet-stream", limit: '50mb'}));
```

---

```
router.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    var url = 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/emotion/v1.0/recognize';
    var requestObject = {
        headers: {
            'content-type':'application/octet-stream',
            'ocp-apim-subscription-key':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        },
        url: url,
        body: req.body
    };
    var handleResponse = function(error, response, body){
        res.send(body);
    };
    request.post(requestObject, handleResponse);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This most likely will not help , I too have the same problem using python , however if you were to send a url link it would work fine. This is Microsoft Server side issue and needs to be address

regards