# APIErrorException: (BadArgument) 'recognitionModel' is incompatible :AZURE COGNITIVE FACE

Tags: python, azure, face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I'm creating an attendance system using AZURE COGNITIVE FACE API. I am storing the attendance in an excel sheet. But there occurs an error " 'recognitionModel' is incompatible." From the documentation I have come to know that there are two recognition models(recognition_01 , recognition_02). Is it required to mention the type? If so how to do it in python?

**ERROR:**

```
  File "identify.py", line 58, in <module>
    res = face_client.face.identify(faceIds, global_var.personGroupId)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\cognitiveservices\vision\face\operations\_face_operations.py", line 313, in identify
    raise models.APIErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.models._models_py3.APIErrorException: (BadArgument) 'recognitionModel' is incompatible.
```

**CODE:**

```
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.models import TrainingStatusType, Person, SnapshotObjectType, OperationStatusType
import global_variables as global_var
import os, urllib
import sqlite3
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string
from openpyxl.cell import Cell
import time
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)



#get current date
currentDate = time.strftime("%d_%m_%y")
wb = load_workbook(filename = "reports.xlsx")
sheet = wb['Cse16']

def getDateColumn():
    for i in range(1, len(list(sheet.rows)[0]) + 1):
        col = get_column_letter(i)
        if sheet['%s%s'% (col,'1')].value == currentDate:
            return col

Key = global_var.key


ENDPOINT = 'https://centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com'
face_client = FaceClient(ENDPOINT,CognitiveServicesCredentials(Key))


connect = sqlite3.connect("Face-DataBase")


attend = [0 for i in range(60)] 

currentDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
directory = os.path.join(currentDir, 'Cropped_faces')
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
        print(filename)
        img_data = open(os.path.join(directory,filename), 'r+b')
        res = face_client.face.detect_with_stream(img_data)
        print("Res = {}".format(res))

        if len(res) < 1:
            print("No face detected.")
            continue

        faceIds = []
        for face in res:
            faceIds.append(face.face_id)
        res = face_client.face.identify(faceIds, global_var.personGroupId)   #Error occuring line
        #print(filename)
        print("res = {}".format(res))

        for face  in res:
            if not face['candidates']:
                print("Unknown")
            else:
                personId = face['candidates'][0]['personId']
                print("personid = {}".format(personId))
                #cmd =  + personId
                cur = connect.execute("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE personID = (?)", (personId,))
                #print("cur = {}".format(cur))
                for row in cur:
                    print("aya")
                    print("row = {}".format(row))
                    attend[int(row[0])] += 1
                print("---------- " + row[1] + " recognized ----------")
        time.sleep(6)

for row in range(2, len(list(sheet.columns)[0]) + 1):
    rn = sheet.cell(row = row, column  =1).value
    if rn is not None:
        print("rn = {}".format(rn))
        rn = rn[-2:]
        if attend[int(rn)] != 0:
            col = getDateColumn()
            print("col = {}".format(col))
            sheet['%s%s' % (col, str(row))] = 0

wb.save(filename = "reports.xlsx")
```

Comment: https://dev.cognitive.azure.cn/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395239

Comment: @Sajeetharan I tried both models but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the services documentation portal (for example [here](https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395239) for West Europe but is the same for all regions) for `Identify` operation:

> The 'recognitionModel' associated with the query faces' faceIds should
>   be the same as the 'recognitionModel' used by the target person group
>   or large person group.

So it looks like you have a mismatch here. You don't have to pass the recognitionModel in the `Identify` operation but in the `Detect` operation that you are doing first.

And you must ensure that this value is the same as the one used for your personGroup where you want to identify the person (see personGroup create [operation](https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395244), containing the recognition variable)

Comment: Yeah I found out that there is a mismatch. Thanks for the info