# Azure Face API gives APIErrorException: (InvalidRequest) Invalid request has been sent

Tags: python, azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am calling Azure Face API using its python sdk. I am getting the following response :-

[image]

I have also checked Monetring in Azure portal it shows this:-

[image]

When i check it in the Azure price calculator it shows:-

[image]

I am using Azure Cognitive Services for Computer Vision, everything works fine, but don't know why only Face API throws exception.
I have also tried similar images with the same code, it works fine with my other account's credentials but still I am facing this error.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Face Service Invalid Request API Error On Running Quickstart Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72776677/azure-face-service-invalid-request-api-error-on-running-quickstart-code)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT No, this is not a solution

Comment: Demo and Quikstart code works but only throws exception in Face API. Becuse i can use the same code with other credentials. But unable to do with newly created Face API credentials.

Comment: @DeepDave-MT I am not using Face identification or Face verification, it requires special permission, i am using face_attributes. Please read the question carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you are facing is due to the latest updates of Face API product, which is detailed in [this blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/responsible-ai-investments-and-safeguards-for-facial-recognition/?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365).

In a few words, some features have been disabled.

In particular:

> In another change, **we will retire facial analysis capabilities that
> purport to infer emotional states and identity attributes such as
> gender, age, smile, facial hair, hair, and makeup**. We collaborated
> with internal and external researchers to understand the limitations
> and potential benefits of this technology and navigate the tradeoffs.
> In the case of emotion classification specifically, these efforts
> raised important questions about privacy, the lack of consensus on a
> definition of “emotions,” and the inability to generalize the linkage
> between facial expression and emotional state across use cases,
> regions, and demographics. API access to capabilities that predict
> sensitive attributes also opens up a wide range of ways they can be
> misused—including subjecting people to stereotyping, discrimination,
> or unfair denial of services.
>
> To mitigate these risks, we have opted to not support a
> general-purpose system in the Face API that purports to infer
> emotional states, gender, age, smile, facial hair, hair, and makeup.
> Detection of these attributes will no longer be available to new
> customers beginning June 21, 2022, and existing customers have until
> June 30, 2023, to discontinue use of these attributes before they are
> retired.

In your code, you are asking for some of these attributes (gender & age) so you should remove those attributes and try again.

Comment: Hi Dear, I am still facing the same issue even without face attributes `detected_faces = face_client.face.detect_with_stream(byte_io ,detection_model='detection_01')`

Comment: Sorry but it's impossible to go deeper without more details. Can you check the APIErrorException: if it has a body, it might include more details about the incorrect request

Answer (score 0):

Because of [updates to Azure's Responsible AI policy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/responsible-ai-investments-and-safeguards-for-facial-recognition/), many features of the Face API are locked down except for Limited Access customers. This includes returning the [Face ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/detect-analyze-recognize-faces/6-compare-match-detected-faces) that the face service creates and uses internally. See [this Microsoft thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1179278/azure-face-api-invalid-request-json-parsing-error?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1175171#newest-answer-comment).

It's not very clear in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-face/azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.operations.faceoperations?view=azure-python-preview), but the default value of the `return_face_id` parameter (something that is now Limited Access / locked down) of both the `detect_with_stream` and `detect_with_url` methods of the `FaceOperations` class (which is the `face` attribute of instances of `FaceClient`) is `True`, i.e. ***by default*** the SDK sends API calls that try to do restricted operations.

If you change `return_face_id` to `False`, you will be able to use the API (provided you don't try to use other locked down / Limited Access features).

**TL;DR:**
Instead of

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face import FaceClient
...
face_client = FaceClient(endpoint, credentials) 
detected_faces = face_client.face.detect_with_stream(...)
```

do

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face import FaceClient
...
face_client = FaceClient(endpoint, credentials) 
detected_faces = face_client.face.detect_with_stream(..., return_face_id=False)
```

The same also applies for `detect_with_url` instead of `detect_with_stream`.