# Getting APIErrorException while using Azure Face API

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am struggling with writing a function to detect faces using Azure's Face API. I am getting an "Invalid Request" when using the API and I am unsure why it is raising this exception, despite me calling the API correctly(I think). I have posted the error and function below.

Note: I am only using the Detection Model, which is not restricted by Microsoft.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/diptobiswas/Downloads/FaceBlurLocal/FacePlateBlur.py", line 263, in <module> main() File "/Users/diptobiswas/Downloads/FaceBlurLocal/FacePlateBlur.py", line 231, in main faces = getFaceAnalysisResultURL(url) File "/Users/diptobiswas/Downloads/FaceBlurLocal/FacePlateBlur.py", line 121, in getFaceAnalysisResultURL detected_faces = face_client.face.detect_with_url(url=img_url) File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/vision/face/operations/_face_operations.py", line 547, in detect_with_url raise models.APIErrorException(self._deserialize, response) azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.models._models_py3.APIErrorException: (InvalidRequest) Invalid request has been sent.`

Here is the function that I have written. You can use the following image URL to reproduce the problem.

img_url = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/8199607/pexels-photo-8199607.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2"

```py
def getFaceAnalysisResultURL (img_url):
    
    # MAKE SURE THAT THE KEY & ENDPOINT ARE VALID
    KEY = "***MY_SECRET KEY***"

    ENDPOINT = "https://SECRET_NAME_OF_RESOURCE.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"

    # Create an authenticated FaceClient.
    face_client = FaceClient(ENDPOINT, CognitiveServicesCredentials(KEY))

    detected_faces = face_client.face.detect_with_url(url=img_url, detection_model='detection_02')

    return detected_faces
```

Comment: Can you please check your Key , Endpoint and Image_url again as code provided by you does work and was able to detect the faces in the URL you shared

Comment: I changed it from a python SDK call to a call using the REST API and that fixed the problem for me. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Because of [updates to Azure's Responsible AI policy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/responsible-ai-investments-and-safeguards-for-facial-recognition/), many features of the Face API are locked down except for Limited Access customers. This includes returning the [Face ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/detect-analyze-recognize-faces/6-compare-match-detected-faces) that the face service creates and uses internally. See [this Microsoft thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1179278/azure-face-api-invalid-request-json-parsing-error?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1175171#newest-answer-comment).

It's not very clear in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-face/azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.operations.faceoperations?view=azure-python-preview), but the default value of the `return_face_id` parameter (something that is now Limited Access / locked down) of both the `detect_with_stream` and `detect_with_url` methods of the `FaceOperations` class (which is the `face` attribute of instances of `FaceClient`) is `True`, i.e. ***by default*** the SDK sends API calls that try to do restricted operations.

If you change `return_face_id` to `False`, you will be able to use the API (provided you don't try to use other locked down / Limited Access features).

**TL;DR:**
Instead of

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face import FaceClient
...
face_client = FaceClient(endpoint, credentials) 
detected_faces = face_client.face.detect_with_stream(...)
```

do

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face import FaceClient
...
face_client = FaceClient(endpoint, credentials) 
detected_faces = face_client.face.detect_with_stream(..., return_face_id=False)
```

The same also applies for `detect_with_url` instead of `detect_with_stream`.

**Note:** I had the same issue, and copy-pasted above the same answer I gave to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72893410/azure-face-api-gives-apierrorexception-invalidrequest-invalid-request-has-bee/78168240#78168240) that resolved the issue.